# Updating label image in tKinter works, but I'm not sure why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Ok, so I've got a project in tKinter, that includes a label with an image, and an entry box. What I need to happen is that the image changes depending on the text in the entry box. Here's the relevant code:

```
from tkinter import *


def go():
    art = PhotoImage(file=str(entry.get() + ".png"))
    portrait = Label(root, image=art)
    portrait_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    print(z1)


root = Tk()
root.title("Window Title")

art = PhotoImage(file="image1_.png")
portrait = Label(root, image=art)
portrait1.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

goButt = Button(root, text="Go", command=go)
goButt.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried many different ways of getting this (having the label image update) to work, but is the only one that has been successful.

You may notice the `print(z1)` command in the `go()` function. `z1` is not a defined variable and isn't used anywhere else in the code, but without it, hitting the `Go` button removes the old image, but leaves the label blank (i.e. the new image doesn't load). Removing that bit of code, or defining `z1` in any way (e.g. `z1 = 1`) does the same thing.

Now so far, having `print(z1)` doesn't negatively affect the project in any way, but having it in there is kind of annoying. I was wondering if anyone could explain **why** the project only seems to work with that bit of code (and why it only works if it's undefined), and if there is a way to get rid of it safely.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in the code you posted, with the label widget name being `portrait`, `portrait1` and `portrait_1`. After fixing that it seems to work like this:

The function `go()` creates a new Label (portrait). This is not the same label that you created earlier, but a new one which only exists inside the function `go()`. Then you put an image in the label and place it in the root window. The name of the image only exists inside the function `go()` which means that it will be garbage collectes when the function ends.

The line `print(z1)` stops the program before the function ends and thus keeps the reference to the image. Without the line `print(z1)`the function will exit, the reference to the image will be garbage collected and the label can no longer find the image.

The usual way to do it is to update the label with `.config()` and then to save a reference to the image in the label widget:

```
from tkinter import *

def go():
    new = PhotoImage(file=str(entry.get() + ".png")) # Create new image
    portrait.config(image=new)  # Update label with new image
    portrait.image = new        # Save reference to the image

root = Tk()
root.title("Window Title")

art = PhotoImage(file="image1_.png")
portrait = Label(root, image=art)
portrait.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

goButt = Button(root, text="Go", command=go)
goButt.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```